# $stateChangeStart don't work when user refresh browser

Tags: angularjs, events, angular-ui-router, state

Please,
I'm using ui-router on my project. `$stateChangeStart` event work fine when the user navigate between the states.
But it doesn't work if I refresh the browser.

This is my source code:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('app.overlay')
    .directive('ibLoading', ['$rootScope' , '$timeout', loading]);

    function loading($rootScope , $timeout){
        console.log("In dirrective");
        var directive = {
            restrict:'EAC',
            link:link
        };

        function link(scope, element) {

            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
                    $timeout(function(){
                        element.addClass('show');
                    } , 50);
              });

              $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
                    $timeout(function(){
                        element.removeClass('show');
                    } , 700);
              });

        }

        return directive;
    }
})();
```

my layout file

```
<div ng-controller="ShellController as vm">
<header class="clearfix">
    <ht-top-nav navline="vm.navline"></ht-top-nav>
</header>
<section id="content" class="content">
    <!--<div ng-include="'app/layout/sidebar.html'"></div>-->
    <div ui-view></div>
    <div class="ib-loading">Loading ...</div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code examples?

Comment: That would depend on where it is used. Without any code nobody can help you. Please provide relevant code

Comment: Are you expecting directive to register the initial change when page is loaded? It won't. Still not clear what problem is or what expected behavior is

Comment: the directive is register but the event is not 'captured' when the browser is refresh.. You can't only see in log **In dirrective**.

Comment: Can you please share your states configuration?  And where do you use it? May be some sample code, pseudo code will also help, @charlietft suggest... There is not information. ;)

Comment: Where in page is directive used? This should be done using scope variables and `ng-class` or `ng-show` first of all. Also first state change will have started before directive is compiled probably

Comment: I use a directive in my layout file.

Comment: Create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates problem

Comment: `layout file` is meaningless to us. Tells us nothing about the html structure

Comment: thank @DaveAmit , I moved it to my index.html file ( the first line, out of any controller) and it work's fine.

Comment: Awesome news! Keep up the good work!

Comment: I have the same problem and I didn't understand what the solution is. You moved what to the index.html file?

Answer (score 1):

A user refresh does not fire $stateChangeStart or $stateChangeSuccess. However **$viewContentLoading** and **$viewContentLoaded** does fire.

So can you try the following:

```
         $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoading', function() {
                $timeout(function(){
                    element.addClass('show');
                } , 50);
          });
          $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
                $timeout(function(){
                    element.removeClass('show');
                } , 700);
          });
```

Comment: yeah but you can't grab the state with these, or is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Here if you change your state you can see your state in console but if you reload your page it will reload the state

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
    console.log("Switching To: ", toState.name);
});
```